# Good strategy for reliable clock in Android?

Tags: android

I'm working on an application that needs to synchronize with a webserver if 24 hours have passed. Every interaction is logged in the database so that I can keep track of the last sync time, so when the application starts, it checks the database to see if it's time for a sync.

So far, I've found no suitable clock for a reliable and consistent time measure, clocks are either temporary (measuring the up-time) or their dates can be changed by the user, so is there any good strategy for dealing with these kind of problems?

Comment: would the world blow up if a user changed their device's clock and caused an early (or late) sync?

Comment: In a word, no: users will always be able to change the clock. Your only real recourse is to make a request and check on the *server* side if it's been more than 24 hours since their last checkin.

Comment: @MarcB I'm thinking of this problem in terms of other applications as well, where perhaps it would be necessary to get the exact time since a sync, which would be quite difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a common problem for *everyone* in software engineering and the only correct answer is: not without a network call.
Measuring time is something you cannot do universally. timezones, different user clocks, daylight savings, all that stuff **will** happen. Either use `System.elapsedRealTime()` and something like boot listeners or ask a server what the time is (this is actually a *bad* idea because it can a) fail b) be terrible slow c) cost the user money and d) wastes battery.
Another thing you could do is to automatically sync every day on a specific time (like 4am). This will not help with the user changing the time or DST but it will work in 99% of all scenarios. Users generally do not change their time a lot :)

Comment: Yes I guess that the worst thing that can happen is that the application will wait at most up to another 24 hours before syncing again if the user decides to tamper with the date. Thanks for the suggestions.